# Difference between 'is' and 'as' keyword in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of keyword 'is' and 'as'. I understand 'is' is the type check operator (to check if a variable is of certain subclass) while the 'as' is the type cast operator (to downcast a variable to its subclass).

However, my question is if there are areas where those two keywords can be used interchangeably and if there are areas that they can't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following are basically identical:

```
if let _ = myObject as? SomeClass ...
if myObject is SomeClass ...
```

The only real difference is that `as` converts it to the resultant class for you to then use. In the code above I used the placeholder "_", which means I don't really want the result. You will find you don't use `is` as much in Swift as you do in other languages because of the `if let` construct. For example:

```
if let mySomeClass = myObject as? SomeClass {
    // Now I know mySomeClass is a SomeClass so I can use it.
}
```

Comment: You will probably find `is` in the same situations where you would find an isolated `instanceof` without a matching downcast immediately afterwards in other languages. `if-let-as?` combines these two operations.

Comment: And conversely, you will find `as!` in situations where other languages have an unconditional downcast without an `instanceof` check first.

Answer (score 3):

As a newbie to Swift from Objective C background, here is my common way to write the casting, using similar structure of `instanceof` in Objective-C and followed by a casting:

```
if (someObject is someClass) {
  (someObject as! someClass).someFunc()
}

or 

if (someObject is someClass) {
  let anObject = (someObject as! someClass)
  anObject.someFunc()
}
```

It can be simplified with **[Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)**:

```
if let anObject = someObject as? someClass {
    anObject.someFunc()
}
```

Some prefer to reuse the object name (not introducing new names to code):

```
if let someObject = someObject as? someClass {
    someObject.someFunc()
}
```

If the body of `if-let-as?` is just one function call, it can be further simplified with **[Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)**:

```
(someObject as? someClass)?.someFunc()
```

When I first migrate from Obj-C to Swift, I let the Xcode compiler to suggest correction of my syntax error regarding optional code.  I usually end up with this:

```
(someObject as! someClass).someFunc()
```

However, when I study Apple's **"The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1)"** eBook, I found this can be a trap.  Here is the part of text from section "Type-Casting Operators":

> The as! operator performs a forced cast of the *expression* to the specified *type*. The as! operator returns a value of the specified *type*, not an optional type. If the cast fails, a runtime error is raised. The behavior of x as! T is the same as the behavior of (x as? T)!.

So, when `someObject` isn't `someClass`, the runtime error will crash my app.